# How to write a copy constructor for a template containing std::tuple which is not always copiable

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I have a class template that has a `std::tuple` field, like:

```cpp
template <typename Fp, typename... ArgRefs> class func_wrapper {
  std::decay_t<Fp> func;
  std::tuple<ArgRefs...> args;

public:
  func_wrapper(Fp f, ArgRefs... args)
    : func(f), args(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...) {}

  func_wrapper(const func_wrapper &rhs) noexcept
    : func(rhs.func), args(rhs.args) {}

  func_wrapper(func_wrapper &&rhs) noexcept
      : func(std::move(rhs.func)), args(std::move(rhs.args)) {}

  auto operator()() { /* ... */  }
};
```

The purpose of this class is to turn a function of arbitrary parameters to a function of empty parameter list. So I stored the references of the arguments to the field `args`.

The problem is, the `args` tuple may contain lvalue references and rvalue references, which makes this tuple not copyable when it contains rvalue references. This causes the copy constructor to fail.

```cpp
void foo(int &a1, int &&a2) {
  a1 = a2 + 1;
}

void test(int x) {
  using F = decltype(foo);
  auto fw1 = func_wrapper<F, int &, int &&>(foo, x, 10);
  // Error
  auto fw2 = fw1;
  // Success
  auto fw3 = std::move(fw1);
}
```

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -c
test.cpp:13:23: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::tuple<int &, int &&>'
    : func(rhs.func), args(rhs.args) {}
                      ^    ~~~~~~~~
```

In this case, the `args` tuple has an `int &&` element, which makes the tuple not able to be copy-initialized. But I want the `func_wrapper` to be copyable. So, is there any way that I can re-implement the copy constructor to make this class copyable?

It seems that the move constructor can always work. But unfortunately, I can not always move the object of this class. A library function I call requires the object to be copied.

Comment: What do you expect the `args` member of the copied `func_wrapper` to hold when the tuple can't be copied? How do you expect the copied `func_wrapper` to use its un-copyable `args`? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. You will probably need to make `args` be a `tuple*` pointer, and have multiple `func_wrapper` objects point to the same `tuple` object in memory when making copies. In which case case, have a look at `shared_ptr` to manage that.

Comment: SFINAE it out with another template?

Comment: @Taekahn I thought about SFINAE at first, but that would disable the copy constructor if the tuple is not copyable, which would violate the OP's "I want the func_wrapper to be copyable" requirement. `if constexpr` *might* be usable, but that would require the `tuple` to be default-constructable, at least, and then the copy constructor could skip assigning values to the `tuple` when using non-copyable types. But that goes back to my earlier comment - what should the `tuple` of a copied `func_wrapper` actually hold when the `tuple` can't be copied.

Comment: Why would you want to be able to copy an object that contains a tuple (or any object for that matter) that is not always copyable?    Strikes me as an XY problem.

Comment: I'd expect the copied `args` tuple (within the copied `func_wrapper`) still hold the references (either lvalue reference or rvalue reference) of arguments passing to a function. So that when `operator()()` is called, these arguments' references will be passed to `func` member and invoke it. Suppose I don't what to store values of the arguments as that would cause extra copies, and this `func_wrapper` will be copied several times. @Remy Lebeau

Comment: Yes, the object needs to be copyable, but I didn't realize that the tuple I used to implement this object is not always copyable. I'm seeking for help how can I implement this object. @Peter

Answer (score 0):

Currently I work around this problem by forcing moving the tuple in the copy constructor:

```cpp
  func_wrapper(const func_wrapper &rhs) noexcept
    : func(rhs.func), args(std::move(const_cast<func_wrapper &>(rhs).args)) {}
```

By `const_cast` and `std::move`, I can use tuple's move constructor to initialize the `args` member. Not quite elegent but the problem disappears. Comments are welcomed.